# AngularJs localStorage delete element in loop

Tags: javascript, angularjs, local-storage, ionic-framework

I do not know how can i delete element in localStorage loop
In  save method i add element and check for it duplicate
explain please how can i delete element using for example only id or all values

My Factory

```
.factory('SaveDocuments', function() {
        var documents = [];

            save: function (id, name, link) {
                if(documents.filter(function(a){return a.id==id}).length)
                { alert('conflict!'); }
                else {
                // add to it,
                documents.push({id: id, name: name, link: link});
                // then put it back.
                localStorage.setItem('document', JSON.stringify(documents));
                }

            },

            del: function(id, name, link) {
                if(documents.filter(function(a){return a.id==id}).length) {
                    for (i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++){
                    key = localStorage.key(i);
                    value = localStorage.getItem(key);
                        localStorage.removeItem(value);
                    console.log(value);
                    break;
                }
                }
                else {
                    alert('conflict!');
                }
            }

        }
```

MyController

```
 .controller('PageSearchCtrl', function($scope, ConstSearch, SaveDocuments) {                          
     $scope.saveDocument = function() {                                                                
         //Create new project                                                                          
             $scope.document = [{"id": 1, "name": "new1", "link": "#/const"}];              
             SaveDocuments.save($scope.document[0].id,$scope.document[0].name,$scope.document[0].link);
     };                                                                                                
      $scope.deleteDocument = function () {                                                            
          $scope.document = [{"id": 1, "name": "new1", "link": "#/const"}];                 
          //Create new project                                                                         


SaveDocuments.del($scope.document[0].id,$scope.document[0].name,$scope.document[0].link);    
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend changing your service to something like the following:

```
.factory('SaveDocuments', function () {
    var lsKey = 'document', // the key to store the docs in local storage under
        documents = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(lsKey) || '[]'); // initialise from localStorage

    function saveToLocalStorage() {
        localStorage.setItem(lsKey, JSON.stringify(documents));
    }

    return {
        save: function (id, name, link) {
            if (documents.filter(function (a) {
                return a.id == id;
            }).length) {
                alert('conflict!');
            } else {
                // add to it,
                documents.push({
                    id: id,
                    name: name,
                    link: link
                });
                saveToLocalStorage();
            }

        },

        del: function (id, name, link) {
            // clear all if del() is called with no arguments or null for all args
            if (!id && !name && !link) {
                documents = [];
                saveToLocalStorage();
                return;
            }
            var initialLength = documents.length;
            documents = documents.filter(function (doc) {
                return (!id || doc.id !== id) && (!name || doc.name !== name) && (!link || doc.link !== link);
            });
            // if nothing was removed, show error
            if (documents.length === initialLength) {
                alert('conflict!');
            } else {
                saveToLocalStorage();
            }
        }
    };
});
```

Note that I correctly initialised it from the local storage state when the application starts (so when you reload the page the data is there correctly), used a variable to hold the only key you use to store the data in local storage (to keep the code DRY), and fixed your `del()` method so it keeps ones which don't match the deletion criteria or deletes everything if no arguments passed in, then just overwrites the value in local storage with the updated state.

**NB:** You should test this, I did not do any testing to see if this works.

Comment: that you for answer but method delete (clean all data, i need to clean only one element not all)

Comment: @AntonScherbinin I am aware of that. Do you understand my code? It will only delete all if you call it with no arguments, like `SaveDocuments.del()`. If you don't like that functionality, just remove the first two lines of the first `if` block inside `del()`.

Comment: i understand i call it with arguments but it still delete all data i need to remove only 1 element not all. i call it like this SaveDocuments.del($scope.document[0].id,$scope.document[0].name,$scope.document[0].link);

Comment: Why don't you just call it with the `id`, since I am assuming that is unique and enough to identify the document to delete with? That should work: `SaveDocuments.del($scope.documents[0].id);`. The reason calling it with all 3 properties deletes everything is because they all have the same id, name or link.